# Assignment in conditionals

Tags: php

I've seen a lot this kind of code recently:

```
if ($foo = $bar->getFoo())
{
    baz($foo);
}
```

Is this considered good or bad practice?

For example, the [NetBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBeans) IDE give a notice if you use this kind of code:

> Possible accidental assignment,
> assignments in conditions should be
> avoided

What do you think?

Comment: Did you mean if ($foo == $bar->getFoo()) ?

Comment: No that's the point :)

Comment: This obviously flew over my head :) So the conditional is to check that $bar->getFoo() doesn't cause an error? Is that right?

Comment: Yes. It will first assign the value of $bar->getFoo() to $foo, and then evaluate if $foo is true or false. Of course in my opinion this is error prone because you can easily mistake an assignment operator for a comparison operator. i.e = and ==

Comment: The above comments illustrate why this should be avoided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a useful tool that I have to admit to using on occasion to avoid an extra line for an assignment. On the one hand, it may be bad practice by some because:

- It's not an available idiom in other common languages
- It's less readable

On the other hand:

- Implicit boolean conversion doesn't occur in other languages, but they're widely counted on where they do exist. Conversely, conditional assignment operators exist in Ruby and Javascript (as examples), but not in PHP. Should we limit our use of language constructs only to those found in all similar languages? Probably not.
- Less readable to whom?

I should note that I do try to avoid it because I find it less readable most of the time, but it's purely personal preference for me. Where I find it useful, I use it.

Answer (score 4):

It's an easy way for errors to sneak in, but it's common practise in PHP. Especially during things like directory traversals where you're doing things like `while (($dir = readdir($handle)) !== FALSE)`

If you can avoid it. Avoid it.

Comment: The `!== FALSE` is redundant, but makes the statement more understandable. But why don't use `== TRUE`? It's even more simple!

Comment: readdir returns FALSE if the directory is empty. Otherwise it returns the next item in the directory. You have to check for not false to keep reading. It should do a strict type check with a triple equals.

Answer (score 4):

I use this syntax all the time... I find it 100% readable, because I'm so used to seeing this kind of line. Having an extra line of code for the assignment looks like a waste of space to me.

Comment: Code is meant to be read.  If an extra line of code increases readability -> add a line.  I wouldn't want to inherit your minified code.

Answer (score 3):

While this is valid syntax and the results will be as expected, it is a bad habit.  The readability is lacking, there is a potential to develop a bad habit of putting = when you meant ==, and your eyes will keep returning to this line when you are trying to find real bugs within an application.  I would not use this writing style.  In this case, just get the return value and then verify the return value... or better yet, use exception handling to avoid getting bogged down with lots of if statements.

Comment: +1 this is a leftover from C days, where this was common (bad) practice.  A lot of people still do this because they think it makes them [look clever](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101875/what-are-some-programming-questions-or-mistakes-you-get-wrong-only-as-you-get-b/2151844#2151844).